# Convert int list to string in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I tried to write a function that converts an int list to a string, for example:

input [1;2;3;4] output "[1;2;3;4]"

input [1] output "[1]"

input [] output "[]"

Here is my code,

```
let covert (ls : int list) : string = 
    let rec c ls l =
      match ls with
      | [] -> "[]"
      | h::t -> c t (l ^ ";" ^string_of_int(h) )
    in c ls ""
```

It doesn't work for [1], it actually returns "[]", can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why does the terminating condition return `"[]"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that your function `c` receives a parially built result (the `l` parameter) but you ignore it when reaching the end of the list.

The `[]` case should return a string containing `l`, not `"[]"`.

I also see possible problems making sure the results show the list in the correct order.

Comment: You meant "partially built string" since he's building `l ^ string_of_int h` ;-) (guess like me you got confused by the choice of variable name, l instead of s)

Comment: I fixed this error, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Advice for these kinds of assignments: Consider the similarities that occur in every output. In this case, it's `[...]` (the brackets). So just write a function that returns the inner stuff and then put the brackets around the result. Therefore, you do not need the extra case `"[]"`, which only handles the case when `ls = []`. You always return `"[]"`, and throw the middle part away.`

A short function I could think of is:

```
let convert ls = "[" ^ String.concat ";" (List.map string_of_int ls) ^ "]"
```

or

```
let convert ls = "[" ^ your_function ^ "]"
```